# Bash script to automatically zip different subfolders and store the zipped files into a special folder with dated names

Tags: linux, bash, zip, 7zip

My directory structure is thus:

```
\myproject\
     src\
     include\
     zipdir\
     .vscode\
     auto7zip.bat
```

There are specific files from within `.vscode\` subfolder that I would like to archive, and not the entire folder.

On windows, the `auto7zip.bat` file has the following content:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set TODAY=%date%
ECHO %TODAY%
    
set path="c:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%
set projectdir=%CD%
set "zipdirsrc=%projectdir%\src"
set "zipdirinc=%projectdir%\include"
set "zipdirothers=%projectdir%\.vscode"
set "movedir=%projectdir%\zipdir"

pushd %zipdirsrc%
ECHO Zipping all contents of %zipdirsrc% and moving archive src to %movedir%
7z a -tzip "%movedir%\src_%TODAY%.zip" -r "%zipdirsrc%\*.*" -mx5
ECHO SRC Task Complete ...

pushd %zipdirinc%
ECHO Zipping all contents of %zipdirinc% and moving archive include to %movedir%
7z a -tzip "%movedir%\include_%TODAY%.zip" -r "%zipdirinc%\*.*" -mx5
ECHO INCLUDE Task Complete ...

pushd %zipdirothers%
ECHO Zipping all other contents of %zipdirothers% and moving archive others to %movedir%
7z a -tzip "%movedir%\others_%TODAY%.zip" -r "%zipdirothers%\*.json" "%zipdirothers%\Makefile" "%zipdirothers%\Makefile*.mk" "%zipdirothers%\windows.vcxproj" "%zipdirothers%\nbproject\" -mx5
ECHO OTHERS Task Complete ...

EXIT /B 0
```

This batch file, if run today (July 2nd, 2021) on windows with `7zip` installed creates `include_02-07-2021.zip` which is the zipped version of `include\`, `src_02-07-2021.zip` which is the zipped version of `src\` and `others_02-07-2021.zip` which is the zipped version of the specific files from the `.vscode\` directory. These zipped files are created automatically inside the `zipdir\` directory.

Is there an equivalent bash script that when run from within `\myproject\` accomplishes the same thing on `linux` distributions, in particular, `ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')
echo $today

movedir=../zipdir

function backup() {
    if [[ -n $2 ]]; then
        newname="$2"
    else
        newname="$1"
    fi
    cd "$1"
    [[ -z $custom ]] && custom="./*"
    echo "Zipping all contents of ./$1 and moving archive $newname to $movedir"
    zip "$movedir/${newname}_$today.zip" -r $custom  -9
    unset custom
    cd ..
}

unset custom

backup src
backup include
custom='./*.json ./Makefile ./Makefile*.mk ./windows.vcxproj ./nbproject/'
backup .vscode others
```

### Update 1:

- Removed irrelevant part of answer
- Updated script to exclude root directory from archive by changing into relevant directory (since request was clarified by OP).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out to see if it works and then accept the answer. I really don't want all stuff in `.vscode` to be zipped. There are object files and executable that get built there. I have much tighter control over `src` and `include` folders and no non-code stuff gets into there.

Comment: This works as the `.bat` file on windows as specified in the OP except for one difference. In windows, opening the zip file reveals immediately all the files. With the bash script you have presented, the files are a layer within. That is, opening the zip file leads to a folder within which the files are there. Is there a way to have the files that were zipped immediately appear on opening the zip file?

Comment: @Tryer I changed the function so that it would run the zipping command in each directory to do that for you. When you add new files in the custom variable, you must do it relative to the directory e.g. `./*.json` instead of `.vscode/*.json`